# Activity automatically scrolls to the middle

Tags: android, android-activity

When i open an activity it  automatically scrolls to the middle..When i open the fragment which has same layout xml file that the activity has it opens fine without scrolling..
I tried putting

```
   View view=getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            view.scrollTo(0,0);
```

but it doesn't worked..
Why my activity automatically scrolls to middle and how can i adjust it so that it opens without scrolling?

```
public class TeamDetails extends FragmentActivity {
    ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_details);
        getActionBar().hide();
View view=getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        view.scrollTo(0,0);
        view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        String[] web = {
                "     dfg",
                "     fs",
                "     sfdf",
                "     fsdf",
                "     sdfdsf",
                "     sdf",
                "     ewr",
                "     urt",
                "     wrw",
                "     zgv",

        } ;
     int[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.ply1, R.drawable.ply2,
                R.drawable.ply3, R.drawable.ply4,
                R.drawable.ply5, R.drawable.ply6,
                R.drawable.ply7, R.drawable.ply8,
                R.drawable.ply9, R.drawable.ply10
        };
        CustomGridSingle adapter = new CustomGridSingle(TeamDetails.this, web, mThumbIds);

        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);



       iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              finish();
            }
        });
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
        iv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TeamDetails2 fragment = new TeamDetails2();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();

            }
        });
        iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
        iv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TeamDetails4 fragment = new TeamDetails4();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
            }
        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.ply1, R.drawable.ply2,
                R.drawable.ply3, R.drawable.ply4,
                R.drawable.ply5, R.drawable.ply6,
                R.drawable.ply7, R.drawable.ply8,
                R.drawable.ply9, R.drawable.ply10
        };

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
    }

}
```

layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout40"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#12abee"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close1"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView23"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowleftside"
            />

        <textview
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView15"
            android:text=" | "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            android:textSize="30dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_rgtside"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout40"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="none"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout15"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout16"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout17"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/layout18"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/layout19"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



                                    <textview
                                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"



                                        android:layout_below="@+id/layout20"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                                        android:text="Hyderabad Hotshots"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                        android:textColor="#000000"
                                        android:textSize="23dp"
                                       />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
                                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
                                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/hyd_team2"
                                        android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:cropToPadding="false" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                                </RelativeLayout>

                                <textview
                                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/layout19"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:padding="10dp"
                                    android:text="@string/hello"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"

                                    />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <textview
                                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/layout18"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:text="TEAM PLAYERS"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />


                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/layout17"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/gridView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="600dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/layout16"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:columnWidth="600dp"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:numColumns="3"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"></GridView>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <textview
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layout15"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="CAMPAIGN SCHEDULE"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout14"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <textview
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout13"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/hello3"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @mmlooloo layout posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this in `onCreate method`

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout20); 

v.requestFocus();
```

Update:

and remove it from GridView by:

```
mGridView.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: when you open it which wedget is shown? for example imageview by id ... ?

Comment: GridView android:id="@+id/gridView"

Comment: try this: find it then add mGridView.setFocusable(false);

Comment: thanks..tht solved my problem..add it in your answer

Comment: i have not added click event on gridview

Comment: i do not think you will get any problem if everything works accept it else tell me to debugge

Comment: This worked in  one case and didn't on other. I've used `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to parent layout

Answer (score 6):

Jemshit Iskenderov's comment led me to the solution that worked in my case, which was to add

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to the top parent, which happened to be a RelativeLayout.