# using textIsSelectable in textView

Tags: java, android, textview

I use `android:textIsSelectable="true"` for TextView.

To enabled ***copy/select/paste*** For `TextView` it is OK

**Issue**

When I open this activity, it scrolls to middle automatically, like this [Link](https://gifyu.com/image/TcvN)

Why did this problem happen?

This is my layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <data>
            <variable
                name="aboutMbti"
                type="mbtitest.kiars.me.mbti.model.AboutMbti"/>  
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp" >

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_splash_mtbi"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        bind:imageUrl="@{aboutMbti.imageUrl}"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_content_about_mtbi"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_splash_mtbi"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/title_padding"
                        android:text="@{aboutMbti.textContent}"
                        android:textColor="@color/ques_title"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: You mean your textview content not copy after using textIsSelectable=true ?

Comment: no. It is work right .. I can copy/select/... but when I go To activity that it`s layout use this attribute for textView, The activity start from half not from start .. if you see the gif .. understand

Comment: Try `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on `img_splash_mtbi` ImageView

Comment: These questions might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16886077/6891563

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25600552/6891563

Comment: @Segar Zala ..What do you men ? the copy ok but I have a problem with scroll the page

Comment: @Khemu Thanks a lot dear. It is ok :) please add your solution with the answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, According to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6891563/khemraj comment, I Find

Mey solution ...

Just add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to ImageView Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <data>
            <variable
                name="aboutMbti"
                type="mbtitest.kiars.me.mbti.model.AboutMbti"/>  
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp" >

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_splash_mtbi"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:padding="5dp"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        bind:imageUrl="@{aboutMbti.imageUrl}"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_content_about_mtbi"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_splash_mtbi"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/title_padding"
                        android:text="@{aboutMbti.textContent}"
                        android:textColor="@color/ques_title"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Tnx Guys

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You can add either `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` or `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the child layout in `NestedScrollView`

Try below code in your layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...... >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    ...........
```

Comment: dear Thanks ... But It works for the show all activity but The selection Turn off and I can select the textView .. why ?

Comment: As comment of Khemraj, try `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in `RelativeLayout`, so your issue is fixed.